# How to use of laziness in Scheme efficiently?

Tags: performance, scheme, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to encode a small lambda calculus with algebraic datatypes in Scheme. I want it to use lazy evaluation, for which I tried to use the primitives `delay` and `force`. However, this has a large negative impact on the performance of evaluation: the execution time on a small test case goes up by a factor of 20x.

While I did not expect laziness to speed up this particular test case, I did not expect a huge slowdown either. My question is thus: **What is causing this huge overhead with lazy evaluation, and how can I avoid this problem while still getting lazy evaluation?** I would already be happy to get within 2x the execution time of the strict version, but faster is of course always better.

Below are the strict and lazy versions of the test case I used. The test deals with natural numbers in unary notation: it constructs a sequence of `2^24` `suc`s followed by a `zero` and then destructs the result again. The lazy version was constructed from the strict version by adding `delay` and `force` in appropriate places, and adding `let`-bindings to avoid forcing an argument more than once. (I also tried a version where `zero` and `suc` were strict but other functions were lazy, but this was even slower than the fully lazy version so I omitted it here.)

I compiled both programs using `compile-file` in Chez Scheme 9.5 and executed the resulting `.so` files with `petite --program`. Execution time (user only) for the strict version was 0.578s, while the lazy version takes 11,891s, which is almost exactly 20x slower.

#### Strict version

```lisp
(define zero    'zero)
(define (suc x) (cons 'suc x))

(define one   (suc zero))
(define two   (suc one))
(define three (suc two))

(define (twice m)
  (if (eq? m zero)
      zero
      (suc (suc (twice (cdr m))))))

(define (pow2 m)
  (if (eq? m zero)
      one
      (twice (pow2 (cdr m)))))

(define (consume m)
  (if (eq? m zero)
      zero
      (consume (cdr m))))

(consume (pow2 (twice (twice (twice three)))))
```

#### Lazy version

```lisp
(define zero    (delay 'zero))
(define (suc x) (delay (cons 'suc x)))

(define one   (suc zero))
(define two   (suc one))
(define three (suc two))

(define (twice m)
  (delay
    (let ((mv (force m)))
      (if (eq? mv 'zero)
          (force zero)
          (force (suc (suc (twice (cdr mv)))))))))

(define (pow2 m)
  (delay
    (let ((mv (force m)))
      (if (eq? mv 'zero)
          (force one)
          (force (twice (pow2 (cdr mv))))))))

(define (consume m)
  (delay
    (let ((mv (force m)))
      (if (eq? mv 'zero)
          (force zero)
          (force (consume (cdr mv)))))))

(force (consume (pow2 (twice (twice (twice three))))))
```

Comment: I am very familiar with functional programming in general, but not with Scheme or other Lisp-like languages in particular. So if there are any Scheme-specific insights I'm missing, I would be especially glad to hear those.

Comment: FWIW, if I were going to make one function in this program non-lazy, it would be `consume`. There's no point adding all these delays when you know you're going to consume the whole result. Only the functions that return numbers need to be lazy, because that makes it possible to write functions like `is-at-least-twenty?` without having to traverse the whole number.

Comment: That's a good point! I did the experiment to make `consume` strict and this reduced the execution time to 6,336s. So it does seem to make a difference, but it's still a 10x overhead of the lazy version over the strict one.

Comment: My first thought was to use `promise?` in forcing to avoid unnecessary `delay` in every single `suc`, but it looks like Chez scheme does not have `promise?`.

Comment: BTW, why are constructors themselves lazy, as opposed to their arguments? What's the precise lazy evaluation strategy you're following? The one that is implemented does not seem to be Haskell-style.

Comment: The reason for making the constructors themselves lazy was because all the functions I defined expect `delay`ed values as input, so to be able to use constructors as arguments to these functions they needed to return a `delay`ed value themselves. How would you suggest implementing the constructors instead to get something that's closer to Haskell? I'd be happy to try if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can see statistics for the two phases of the test program using ChezScheme's `(time ...)` procedure:

```
$ scheme
Chez Scheme Version 9.5.2
> (load-program "strict.ss")
(time (pow2 (twice (...))))
    21 collections
    0.695561822s elapsed cpu time, including 0.521065634s collecting
    0.695607000s elapsed real time, including 0.521191000s collecting
    672586992 bytes allocated, including 236483824 bytes reclaimed
(time (consume u2^24))
    no collections
    0.037766347s elapsed cpu time
    0.037762000s elapsed real time
    0 bytes allocated
```

and for the lazy version:

```
$ scheme
> (load-program "lazy.ss")
(time (pow2 (twice (...))))
    no collections
    0.000000000s elapsed cpu time
    0.000000000s elapsed real time
    400 bytes allocated
(time (force (consume u2^24)))
    572 collections
    11.997971385s elapsed cpu time, including 10.798406971s collecting
    12.012723000s elapsed real time, including 10.813517000s collecting
    4832215216 bytes allocated, including 4460306000 bytes reclaimed
```

So 90% of time is collecting. Adjusting [collector parameters](http://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/csug9.5/smgmt.html#./smgmt:s12) may improve this, eg:

```
(collect-trip-bytes 1000000)  
(collect-generation-radix (greatest-fixnum))  
(heap-reserve-ratio 2.0)
```

(these values halve lazy time OMM)

One might also replace ChezScheme's `delay` and `force` with stripped down versions:

```
(import (except (chezscheme) delay force))
        
(define (make-promise p)
  (let ([value (box p)])
    (lambda ()
      (when (box? value)
        (let ([x ((unbox value))])
          (when (box? value)
            (set! value x))))
      value)))
        
(define-syntax delay
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ expr) (make-promise (lambda () expr))]))
    
(define (force promise)
  (promise))
```

(add above to the beginning of lazy.ss)

**NB these have no error checking, and don't handle multiple values or lazy boxes.**
(The ChezScheme implementation is [here](https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme/blob/main/s/4.ss#L388-420))

With these changes the lazy version is about 4x slower than strict:

```
$ scheme
> (load-program "lazy.ss")
(time (pow2 (twice (...))))
    no collections
    0.000000000s elapsed cpu time
    0.000000000s elapsed real time
    336 bytes allocated
(time (force (consume u2^24)))
    3813 collections
    2.977003428s elapsed cpu time, including 2.175818398s collecting
    2.977292000s elapsed real time, including 2.179504000s collecting
    4029652320 bytes allocated, including 2414247968 bytes reclaimed
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed analysis and suggestions to speed things up! I get the feeling that this is probably all one can do, so I've accepted this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very like a problem that crops up in Haskell from time to time. The problem is one of garbage collection.

There are two ways that this can go. Firstly, the lazy list can be consumed as it is used, so that the amount of memory consumed is limited. Or, secondly, the lazy list can be evaluated in a way that it remains in memory all of the time, with one end of the list pinned in place because it is still being used - the garbage collector objects to this and spends a lot of time trying to deal with this situation.

Haskell can be as fast as C, but requires the calculation to be strict for this to be possible.

I don't entirely understand the code, but it appears to be recursively creating a longer and longer list, which is then evaluated. Do you have the tools to measure the amount of memory that the garbage collector is having to deal with, and how much time the garbage collector runs for?

Comment: This is a case where the lazy list is consumed in constant space. The lazy version should be faster than the strict one, precisely because of the tiny size of the live heap during GC. In tried this in Haskell, and the lazy version was 3-4x faster than the strict one.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not `encode a small lambda calculus with algebraic datatypes` but you try to encode the Peano arithmetics, which is the first step up to "a small lambda".

I tried to write you some code that does it in a "faster way".  Because I do not use the special forms `force` and `delay` in my code I used instead thunks to encode their logic.

```
(define succ
  (lambda (x)
    (lambda ()
      (cons 'succ x))))

(define zero (lambda () 'zero))
(define one (succ zero))
(define two (succ one))
(define three (succ two))

(define twice
  (lambda (n)
    (define twice
      (lambda (k)
        (if (eq? 'zero k)
          n
          (succ (twice ((cdr k)))))))
    (twice (n))))

(define pow2
  (lambda (n)
    (if (eq? 'zero n)
      one
      (twice (pow2 ((cdr n)))))))

(define print10
  (lambda (n)
    (define toten
      (lambda (n)
        (if (eq? n 'zero)
          0
          (+ 1 (toten ((cdr n)))))))
    (display (toten (n)))
    (newline))))

(print10 zero)
(print10 one)
(print10 two)
(print10 three)
(print10 (twice three))
(print10 (pow2 (zero)))
(print10 (pow2 (one)))
(print10 (pow2 (two)))
(print10 (pow2 (three)))
```

A test session should look so:

```
% mit-scheme --silent <peano.scm
0
1
2
3
6
1
2
4
8
```

Comment: Please trust me when I say that I know what I am *trying* to do. I know that I technically only defined peano naturals, and three functions over them, however (1) the Peano naturals were meant as a concrete example that can easily be generalized to other datatypes, and (2) I am happy with a shallow embedding so there is no need to define lambdas explicitly.

Comment: Regarding your solution, it looks like only the constructors are still lazy, but the functions twice and pow2 are not. What I want is actually the opposite: I don't particularly care whether the constructors are lazy, but I need the functions to be lazy in their inputs (for reasons that are perhaps not very clear from the example I gave here).